# How to test a SSO using tokens in java?

Tags: java

I have to two applications :
  A : is the parent application
  B  : is the child application.

When the user has to access B , he needs to sign in to A , which creates a token, and then the user can access B with that token

Manually using post-man I was able to test the flow.   **How can I write automation for the same flow. How can my automation test in B access the same token from A and use it ?** My automation will be using the RestAssure lib.

Both the applications are in JAVA.

Manually using post-man this is what I have so far :

```
curl -X POST \
  http://localhost:8080/applicationB/endpoint \
  -H 'authorization: Bearer <token_value>'
```

I got the token_value by login into A that created the token that I used.

Comment: Didn't quite understand what's the problem?  If you are using the restassured library build up the requests, extract data out and pass to subsequent requests.